# Application giving poor performance and errors in profiler trace

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

Java application running against SQL Server 2014 and the customer is complaining about slow performance. A profiler trace shows that the bulk of the stored procedures used by the application are throwing an exception 156

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
```

The pattern in the trace file is:

```
RPC:Starting
Exception
SP:CacheMiss
SP:CacheMiss
SP:StmtStarting
```

So it looks like it complains about a syntax error in the procedure, has two cache misses and then executes the procedure successfully.

Has this been seen before by anyone and any pointers on how to remedy the exception ?

Comment: What is the version of SQLServer you are using,can you also update CPU,memory usage of SQLServer

Comment: Can you post the procedure? I'd fix that part first.

Comment: It is not just one procedure but several and they all run fine from SSMS, that is why I am wondering were the error is coming from. SQL server is 2014, 12gb memory.

Comment: What is the jdbc version you use?

Answer (score 0):

Tracked the issue down to a change in the JDBC connection string, someone had added selectMethod=cursor, once removed application performance returned to normal.

This article helped track down the problem:

http://www.sqlserverfaq.net/2013/03/26/long-blocking-chain-caused-due-to-compile-locks/